# How to bind the object which was present in my dto through spring-mvc forms

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I have my DTO class RegisteredTrainee which has a has-a relation with class DemoInfo means my DTO contains an object of DemoInfo I successfully bind my bean but unable to understand when the DemoInfo object was created and when I called the method of my DTO getDemoInfo() it shows null. Please Help me to understand what was happening.

I also tried @requestparam to get values of that demoInfo Object manually but it shows the form has no attribute named demoInfo.demoTime and the name was exactly same in my springform input-path

here's my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/demoTrainee")
    public ModelAndView generateDemoSlip(RegisteredTrainee regDemoInfo) {
        System.out.println(regDemoInfo.getRegisterationId() + " >>");
        System.out.println(regDemoInfo.getDemoInfo() + " >>");
        boolean bool = TraineeService.demoTrainee(regDemoInfo);
        if (bool)
            return new ModelAndView("enquirytaker/traineeregisteration/registeration/trainee-registeration","trainee",new RegisteredTrainee());
        return null;
    }
```

and here's the DTO

```
package org.mz.trainee.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.mz.ptp.beans.User;

public class RegisteredTrainee extends User {
private String registerationId;
private Date registerationDate;
private String enquiryTaker;
private DemoInfo demoInfo;
private ArrayList<EnrollInfo> enrollInfoList;

public RegisteredTrainee() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getRegisterationId() {
    return registerationId;
}

public void setRegisterationId(String registerationId) {
    this.registerationId = registerationId;
}

public Date getRegisterationDate() {
    return registerationDate;
}

public void setRegisterationDate(Date registerationDate) {
    this.registerationDate = registerationDate;
}

public String getEnquiryTaker() {
    return enquiryTaker;
}

public void setEnquiryTaker(String enquiryTaker) {
    this.enquiryTaker = enquiryTaker;
}

public DemoInfo getDemoInfo() {
    demoInfo = new DemoInfo();
    return demoInfo;
}

public void setDemoInfo(DemoInfo demoInfo) {
    demoInfo = new DemoInfo();
    this.demoInfo = demoInfo;
}

public ArrayList<EnrollInfo> getEnrollInfoList() {
    return enrollInfoList;
}

public void setEnrollInfoList(ArrayList<EnrollInfo> enrollInfoList) {
    this.enrollInfoList = enrollInfoList;
}
}
```

here's the spring form i.e jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demo Trainee Form</h1>
<form:form method="POST" action="demoTrainee" modelAttribute="regDemoInfo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="registerationId">RegId</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="registerationId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="userName">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="gender">Gender</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="gender" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="phone"> Contact Number</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="phone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${demoInfo.demoTime}">Demo Time</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="${demoInfo.demoTime}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${demoInfo.demoDate}">Demo Date</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="${demoInfo.demoDate}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${demoInfo.trainer}">Trainer</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="${demoInfo.trainer}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${demoInfo.training}">Training</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="${demoInfo.training}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${demoInfo.enquiryTaker}">Enquiry Taker</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="${demoInfo.enquiryTaker}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Generate Demo Slip" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `${}`.

```
<tr>
   <td><form:label path="demoInfo.trainer">Trainer</form:label></td>
   <td><form:input path="demoInfo.trainer" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: when I call getDemoInfo() it gives null .Can someone tell me how do i bind that object too.?

Comment: thanks a lot @chaoluo i removed ${ } and I forgot to add a blank constructor in my DemoInfo class so thats why also object was not created and it gives me null. But now it works fine.